# Android Rotate Rectangle with Collision

Tags: android, canvas, rotation, collision, rect

I want to rotate a Rectangle on Canvas, but if I rotate it with canvas.rotate(); and check the collision with rect1.intersect(rect2), it wont check the collision for the new rotated Rect, but the collision for the unrotated Rect. Please Help :) My Code to Rotate and Draw the Rectangle:

```
canvas.save();
roto = new RectF(-1, (int)height / 2 - (int)height / 20, (int)width + 1, (int)height / 2 + (int)height / 20);
if(rotation == true){
    canvas.rotate(degrees, width / 2, height / 2);
    degrees+=4f;
}
canvas.drawRect(roto, paint);
canvas.restore();
```

and to check the Collision:

```
RectF cursor1 = new RectF((int) event.getX(),
            (int) event.getY(), (int) event.getX() + 1,
            (int) event.getY() + 1);

if(cursor1.intersect(game.roto.roto) && play == true){
    game.roto.collision = true;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You're actually just rotating the transformation that the canvas uses for drawing. The rectangle itself stays put. One possible solution is to rotate the cursor by the *opposite* amount, and *then* test for intersection.

Comment: but how to rotate the cursor, it's also a rectangle

Comment: Technically, it's just a point - I assume you're only using a rectangle to use the `RectF.intersect` method. You can actually rotate the point returned by `event.getX()` and `event.getY()` and *then* create the `cursor1` rectangle.